# Early symptoms of memory exhaustion have been detected in this time window

Tags: java, garbage-collection, newrelic

I'm struggling to understand the following error/warning thrown by new relic:

> Early symptoms of memory exhaustion have been detected in this time window.

Below are profile charts based on the logs.

[image: new relic heap logs]

[image: new relic heap logs continuation]

I would like to understand:

1. Why is the Eden Space never clean completely when a minor GC occurs?
2. Based on GC behavior from logs, do blue and yellow correspond to a major GC and minor GC, respectively?
3. Why is GC collecting all the time?
4. The reddish zone is when New Relic throws a memory exhaustion alert. But, the heap is not yet full. Will this trigger a circuit breaker to transit to the open state?

I noticed this behavior when submitting a new REST call to our task executor service (e.g: `executorService.submit(() -> restconecto.post(..))`). I tried submitting a `logger.info()` and it is working ok, but it seems that doing a long poll is the problem. Below is my GC config:

- Parallel GC
- `-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m`

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A garbage collector is a daemon thread and is started when JVM starts and the daemon stops when all non-daemon thread stops. The reason why GC is constantly running, and the application is never clean is most likely because there is always something to collect (it could even be a background task). End user does not have control over garbage collector.
2. Don't understand your question really
3. See 1.
4. Your heap does not have to be full in order to trigger the alert. By default relic settings are set as follows:

   ```
   Memory threshold: 20%
   Garbage collection CPU threshold: 10%
   ```

These can be tuned of course, but what these basically mean is that if available memory is less then the threshold the alert will be triggered.

As you noticed when submitting a REST request (depending on the request actually submitted and how your application is structured/designed) this particular request could be 'heavy' for the application to process therefore it may use more memory then you may expect.

Answer (score 0):

1. The young generation collector you are using is [PS Scavenge](https://bmwieczorek.wordpress.com/tag/ps-scavenge/). This collector using multiple threads in parallel. As such, there isn't a full *stop-the-world* pause that collects all nodes from the young generation. As such, the available space will not likely not go all the way down to 0% for Eden space.
2. The yellow and blue lines on the charts don't correspond to major or minor GC events. It depends on the chart, itself. However, in the *Garbage Collection CPU Time* chart, the yellow area corresponds to the CPU time spent on the young generation collector, PS Scavenge, while the blue area corresponds to the CPU time spent on the old generation collector, PS Mark Sweep.
3. The garbage collector is running all the time because both the young gen, survivor gen, and old gen collectors are using multiple background threads. This minimizes the number of *stop-the-world* pauses that occur periodically in single-threaded garbage collectors.
4. Based on what I can tell from the charts, yes. The red-zone is a period of time during which New Relic makes the determination that it needs to potentially pause the program and completely clean up the heap so that the program can continue running. Usually, concurrent collectors just end up delaying stop-the-world pauses, as opposed to preventing them entirely. See [Gil Tene's seminal talk](https://youtu.be/we_enrM7TSY) on Garbage Collection for details. For details on the conditions under which the circuit breaker trips, see [this doc](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/custom-instrumentation/circuit-breaker-java-custom-instrumentation).

Comment: Some comments on your points:
1. If i'm am not wrong i have read that young generation collection is a stop-the-world collection for all 4 GC. The thing with parallel collector is that GC uses multiple threads to do the collection and as a consecuence eden memory should be reclaimed completely after a young collection. I can see that when eden decreses in size, survivor and old increses, however eden is never cleared
4. Thanks for doc link